# How to get current time in Pact / Kadena

Tags: pact, pact-lang

How do you get the current time in pact?
I couldn't find it in the documentation

https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pact-functions.html?highlight=time#time-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer -

It can be found under the `block-time` variable under `chain-data`
[documentation](https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pact-functions.html?highlight=time#time-2)

Example:

```
pact> (chain-data)
{"block-height": 0,"block-time": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"chain-id": "","gas-limit": 0,"gas-price": 0.0,
"prev-block-hash": "","sender": ""}
```